# How to create an iPhone multi-branded App?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ios

I'm going to develop an iPhone app, and want to make sure what I want to do is possible, and will be approved by Apple.

I'm going to create an app that will be fully branded on per submission basis. I want to have one app per customer (our customers are companies) with their logo, skin, etc. 
This apps will be downloaded and installed by the employees of each one of our customers. 
In other words, we would use the same base code (logic doesn't change), but will brand it for each customer. Something similar to what Magento (http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/mobile) does, they created an Ecommerce mobile app, and they brand it to their customer, but the app logic remains the same.

Would Apple consider this as duplicate apps? what is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get on with this? Did your apps get approved? I'm facing a similar situation myself and wondering which route I should take.

Comment: @NathanGaskin see my answer below for the new Volume Purchase Program option that might be what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can say I know of several companies built on this strategy. The code doesn't change one iota from app to app, only images and names change and they continue to bring in revenue.

EDIT: Note this is against apple policy and if they find out they have been known to ban accounts. They consider it spamming and prefer that you sell one app that provides in app purchases. Directly from their feedback on a particular group of app submissions:

> Thank you for submitting your
>   Photography apps to the App Store.
>
> We've completed the review of your
>   apps, however, we are unable to post
>   them to the App Store because they
>   provide the same feature set and
>   simply vary the content. Apps that
>   replicate functionality with different
>   content create clutter in the App
>   Store, hindering users' ability to
>   find apps, and do not comply with the
>   App Store Review Guidelines
>   https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html:
>
> ```
>    2.20   Developers 'spamming' the App Store with many versions of 
>    similar apps will be removed from the
>    iOS Developer Program
> ```

Comment: JakeVA
Who are the companies that you know are multi-brannded apps?

Comment: I won't name the companies because they could be banned.

Answer (score 7):

I would have said "no problem" until I read:

> This apps will be downloaded and
>   installed by the employees of each one
>   of our customers

It sounds like what your creating is (a set of) *private* applications, which are intended to be targeted only to specific users - i.e. employees of the company.

Apple has a separate "enterprise" development program geared towards this - allowing developers to deploy programs for their own company - and do it outside of the App Store.

If your program is very specific towards the companies, Apple may make you do this - rather than putting the Apps up for general consumption on the App store.

See here for more details:

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Also:

*If* your application is really intended for a wider audience, and your could in-fact sell/distribute it a such - you *could* "skin" the app *dynamically*. For example, on first-time launch, when you "register" with some "service" - based upon your email address it could download the appropriate skinning graphics.

Answer (score 4):

You can now use Apple's [Volume Purchase Program](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/) to release differently branded versions of the same app to different customers.  The app can be free or paid.  Each customer must have a DUNS number (Dun & Bradstreet).  See the [FAQ](https://vpp.itunes.apple.com/faq) for details.

Comment: Why the downvote?  The answer is factually correct, relevant, and contains new information that wasn't available at the time the question was asked.  If you're going to "add value" with a downvote, at least explain yourself so someone doesn't just upvote me again and I continue to mislead people.